# React-Native Redux-Toolkit Redux-Persist: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

Here's the error that is shown in Emulator[image]

This error has appeared while I was integrating redux-persist with Redux Toolkit in the React-native application. I have tried to find various solutions but failed to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your code, pls?

Comment: The error is clear, the `store` doesn't have dispatch property. Take a look at your store and you probably missed something implementing it

Comment: The `store` is undefined. We can't address issues in code we can't see though. Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working that you suspect causes the issue. Include the complete error message and any error stacktraces. If necessary, please also include exact reproduction steps used to produce the issue.

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question (i.e. I missed adding code snippet). But I have found the issue and resolved it. Would be adding it as answer soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has occurred due to the misplacement of the persistStore() code which needed store as a parameter. Its working fine when placed after the store creation code snippet.

Before (Not Working):

```
export const persistor = persistStore(store); // this line should be after creating the store.

export const store = configureStore({...}); // store creation.
```

After (Working):

```
export const store = configureStore({...}); // store creation.
export const persistor = persistStore(store); // Here it is working fine.
```